# In Rails, how to make random events happen at random times for random users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random

I am looking for a way to make a couple of predefined events as methods happen at random times for random users.

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create `ActiveJobs` and `rake` tasks that will fire them. Example:
In `app/jobs`, create a `share_job.rb` with the following code:

```
require "active_job"
class ShareJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform
    func_to_call = rand(n) # n is the number of methods you have
    case func_to_call
    when 0
      # call first_func
    when 1
      # call second_func
    #...
  end
end
```

Then in `lib/tasks`, create an `execute_job.rake`file with the following code:

```
namespace :execute do
  task execute_random_function: :environment do
    ShareJob.perform_later()
  end
end
```

To run this code manually, type in your `console`:

```
rake execute:execute_random_function
```

You can execute this `job` at a random time using `Scheduler`(a `Heroku` `Add-on`)